# Where can I find a list of SNP rs IDs that belong to the X chromosome?

Tags: snp, phylogenetics

Where can I find a list of SNP rs IDs that belong to the X chromosome?

I'm trying to exclude the SNPs on X-chromosome in a data set, but I don't know where these SNPs come from.

I tried to use [dbSNP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp?term=X%5BChromosome%5D) to search, it returns 26933249 SNPs, but the webpage seems to refuse me to download the information.

Comment: Have you tried the send to option in the top right corner, just below the search bar?

Comment: In what species? Your search didn't specify a species, are you really interested in rsIDs from *any* species?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just searched for `X[Chromosome]`, you didn't specify a species. Presumably, your dataset comes from a specific species, so you should limit your search to that species. For instance, for human, you can search dbSNP for [`X[Chromosome] human[organism]`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=X%5BChromosome%5D%20human%5Borganism%5D). Then, click on the `send to` link at the top left and download the data:

[image: dbSNP screenshot]

This is veeeeeery slow, however. I suggest that you instead download the data for chrX from dbSNP's FTP site (this assumes your species of interest is human): ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606/chr_rpts/chr_X.txt.gz

Once you have this file, you can use it to filter your dataset:

1. Collect all rsIDs from the file:

   ```
   zcat chr_X.txt.gz | awk '/^[0-9]/{print "rs"$1}' > chrX.rsIDs
   ```
2. Filter your dataset.

   You haven't shown the format of your dataset, so if it is just a list of rsIDs like this:

   ```
   $ cat dataset
   rs77669712
   rs199706910
   rs2799940 
   rs12205639
   rs10958205
   rs200778574
   ```

   You can remove any that are on chrX with:

   ```
   $ grep -vxFf chrX.rsIDs dataset 
   rs77669712
   rs199706910
   rs12205639
   rs10958205
   rs200778574
   ```

   That will print all rsIDs from the text file `dataset` that are not also in the text file `chrX.rsIDs`. Note the `-x` option for `grep` which tells it to only consider matches that cover the entire line. This ensures that `rs1234` is not removed when you're looking for `rs123`.